# Does PHP's file_get_contents cache a 301 status code?

Tags: php, caching, redirect, http-status-code-301, status

If PHP does cache a permanent redirect:

1. For how long?
2. Can this period be changed?

I would also be interested in the default behaviour on this matter of Perl, Python, and any other languages used primarily for web development

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `http_fopen_wrapper.c` which is used by `file_get_contents()` contains no caching logic whatsoever. In particular it responds to the `Location:` header only, and does not care for the actual HTTP status code. (It does not notice if it's a temporary redirect or a permanent.)

Comment: Thx mario, my tests confirm the same. Even when responding with a 301, the "old" URI is still hit every single time.

Answer (score -1):

If you want more direct control over your http queries I suggest using [curl](https://www.php.net/curl).

Comment: This doesn't answer his question at all, and should probably be posted as a comment.

Comment: I am serving the response header so do not have any control of the client's behaviour. Anyhow, would cURL cache the new location and use it on subsequent requests?